# Display a piece of Text many times by placing code only

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to display a text or sentence, say "water is life" many times, by placing code only, without the writing it over and over. 
Means whenever I'll place the code the text/sentence will be displayed.
With the help of CSS and javascript

Comment: The answer to your *question* is **Yes**... Now if you show what you have tried we might show *how* to fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With css pesudo code:

```css
.water:after {
  content: "water is life";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- IE -->
<p class='water'></p>
<p class='water'></p>
<p class='water'></p>
```

With js, you can either make function for writing the text:

```js
var out = function() {
  document.write('<p>water is life</p>');
};
for (var i = 1; 3 >= i; i++)
  out();
```

Answer (score 1):

For example like this:

**With jQuery**

```
<span class="water-is-life"></span>
...
<div class="water-is-life"></div>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
$('.water-is-life').html("Water is life");
</script>
```

**With AngularJS**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<span>{{ waterIsLife }}</span>
...
<div><b>{{ waterIsLife }}</b></div>
</div>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.waterIsLife = "Water is life";
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was short and simple

Answer (score 1):

```
function writeText(text) {
    document.write(text);
} 

writeText('water is life');
```

You can create a function like that to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would do it server-side with PHP.

```
<?php $text="water is life"; ?>
<!-- Some HTML page content -->
<?php echo $text; ?>
<!-- Some more HTML page content -->
<?php echo $text; ?>
<!-- And so on ... -->
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution in CSS and javascript

Answer (score 0):

This may help...

HTML

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Javascript

```
function myText(){
    var str =  "Water is life"; // Your desired text....
    return str;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myText();
```

[Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37q3q0mu/)

Use `myText()` to display the text...

To print the text more than once try this

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      alert(myText());
}
```

```js
function myText(){
     var str =  "Water is life"; // Your desired text....
     return str;
    }
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    alert(myText());
    }
```